# How to use %like% operator inside a parallel foreach

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I am using foreach using dopar to parallelize a task. Inside the statement I am using the %like%, but I hit an error

> **Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "%like%"**

I thought like was just a wrapper for grep and is part of the base package. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `%like%` is from `data.table`. Did you load that package?

Comment: Don't forget to add `.packages = c("data.table")) %dopar% {` inside your `foreach` statement

Comment: I did not try data.table. I am not sure if it actually belongs to it because I am using matrices and using %like% to subset matrices based on the column names. Let me just try it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the lines below in your code.
I believe you forgot to reference the package.

```
install.packages ('data.table')
library (data.table)
```

Comment: No, I have loaded all the package, but you need to pass the packages separately into the foreach if you are running it in parallel. Let me try passing data.table to it.

Comment: just out of curiosity, a new version of foreach was released recently: https://www.r-bloggers.com/changes-in-the-foreach-package/